# Issue with confidence intervals when using predict() function

Tags: r

I am trying to plot a scatterplot with a regression line and confidence intervals, however after following this (https://www.statology.org/plot-confidence-interval-r/) article my confidence intervals look like the below which is not correct:

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
#finding confidence in ML law vs boron
model <- lm(BML$Boron ~ BML$ML_Law)
summary(model)
newx <- seq(min(BML$ML_Law), max(BML$ML_Law), length.out=25)
preds <- predict(model, newdata = data.frame(x=newx), interval = 'confidence')

#crossplots with all data
plot(BML$Boron ~ BML$ML_Law, col='black', pch=19, xlab="Ocean pH Data Anomaly",
     ylab="\u03B411B Isotopic Record pH Anomaly")
points(alldata$Boron ~ alldata$BATS, col='blue', pch=19)
points(alldata$Boron ~ alldata$HOT, col='orange', pch=19)
points(alldata$Boron ~ alldata$SODA, col='green', pch=19)
abline(model)
lines(newx, preds[ ,3], lty = 'dashed', col = 'blue')
lines(newx, preds[ ,2], lty = 'dashed', col = 'blue')
```

My data looks like this:

```
structure(list(Year = c("Jan 1872", "Jan 1882", "Jan 1887", "Jan 1892", 
"Jan 1912", "Jan 1917", "Jan 1922", "Jan 1927", "Jan 1932", "Jan 1937", 
"Jan 1942", "Jan 1947", "Jan 1952", "Jan 1957", "Jan 1962", "Jan 1967", 
"Jan 1972", "Jan 1977", "Jan 1982", "Jan 1987", "Jan 1992", "Jan 1997", 
"Jan 2002", "Jan 2007", "Jan 2012"), ML_Law = c(0.01500006, 0.00802408, 
0.005794975, 0.004998124, -0.002354516, -0.005305801, -0.006265274, 
-0.010072961, -0.009472531, -0.014490683, -0.014980646, -0.014092611, 
-0.014782765, -0.018102521, -0.021763204, -0.02585805, -0.031586143, 
-0.03846917, -0.046054884, -0.054084116, -0.061592271, -0.068916747, 
-0.077981922, -0.087936314, -0.097452513), Boron = c(-0.0971860000000007, 
-0.0981860000000001, -0.0831859999999995, -0.0831859999999995, 
-0.0771860000000011, -0.0561860000000003, -0.0881860000000003, 
-0.079186, -0.124186, -0.115186, -0.0981860000000001, -0.0961859999999994, 
-0.0981860000000001, -0.126186000000001, -0.129186000000001, 
-0.0861859999999997, -0.111186, -0.145186000000001, -0.0921859999999999, 
-0.148186000000001, -0.137186, -0.179186000000001, -0.147186, 
-0.140186, -0.149186)), row.names = c(NA, -25L), class = "data.frame")
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: change your `lm()` call to this: `model <- lm(Boron ~ ML_Law,data=BML)`, and your `predict()` call to this: `preds <- predict(model, newdata = data.frame(ML_Law=newx), interval = 'confidence')`

Comment: I'll place as answer, just to close it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your lm() call to this:

```
model <- lm(Boron ~ ML_Law,data=BML)
```

and your predict() call to this:

```
preds <- predict(model, newdata = data.frame(ML_Law=newx), interval = 'confidence')
```